# switch screen and display image in Processing

Tags: processing

I am making an animation using Processing 3, I would like to know how can I switch screen smoothly?
each screen contains different images.
Also, if for example, I would like an image to appear at the end, how can I do that, is it to do with time?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program), and you need to be much more specific about exactly what you want to do: what do you mean by switching screens smoothly? What screens? What does smoothly mean in this context?

But I'll try to help in a general sense.

First, you need to store the **state** of your sketch in variables at the top of your code. This might be a series of `boolean` values representing which screen should be shown. Then you need to change those variables when you want the display to change: this can be in response to user input, or like you said a timer of some kind, or a combination of the two. Finally, you just need to draw each frame based on those variables.

Here's an example that stores a very simple state in a single variable, sets the variable in some event functions, and uses that variable to figure out what to draw each frame:

```
boolean showRed = false;

void mousePressed(){
  showRed = true;
}

void keyPressed(){
 showRed = false; 
}

void draw(){
 if(showRed){
   background(255, 0, 0);
 }
 else{
   background(0);
 }
}
```

This is just a general answer to show you the kind of thing you need to be doing. Again, you need to break your problem down into smaller and more specific steps, and then take those smaller steps on one at a time. If you get stuck, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I just started to learn Processing, that helps, but I am doing an animation and want to switch screen without using any clicks, could you please offer some help for this?

Comment: @joe The idea is the same. You'd represent your sketch as a series of variables, and change them whenever you want. My example uses clicks and key presses, but nothing is stopping you from using the end of an animation to change the state. Have you tried putting together a MCVE?